# Building a simple Information Database using python & Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I'm working on a simple information DB using python and excel, currently i have excel workbook (db.xlsx) containing 1 sheet with 3 columns and x rows.
columns: (A:employee, B:password, C:email)

the python app should get the user input ("Employee Name") and search for the entered string in column A if found then display the ("password & email") from column B and C

ex:

excel file data:

A,                                   B,                 C

**employee,                            password,            email**

john doe,                   12345,    john@doe.com

Johanna doe,        978765,             johanna@doe.com

> > User input: john doe
> >
> > employee name: john doe - password : 12345, email: john@doe.com

also i would like the app to ask me to add new record if employee name is not in the excel file.

this is the code i wrote so far, i cannot continue to write the rest of the code as i'm stuck in the search & display data part.

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook('db.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('QA')

q1 = raw_input('Enter Employee Name: ')
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row):
    if sheet.cell(row=row, column=0).value == q1:
        for j in range(i, sheet.max_column):
            print (sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
```

your help is kindly appreciated.

Update: 
This is the working code after changing #if sheet.cell(row=row, column=0).value == q1:   to  if sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value == q1: as Gordon13 suggested, Thanks

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook('db.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('QA')
while True:
    q1 = raw_input('Input: ')
    for row in range(1, sheet.max_row):
        if sheet.cell(row=row , column=1).value == str(q1):
            print sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value
            print sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value
```

Comment: can you explain further what the issue is

Comment: i'm looking for a code to do the search function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain exactly what you're seeing when you run your code?

I think I see a small issue with your loop indices, but I can't be sure unless you describe what's happening

This is untested, but I think it should be closer to what you want:

```
from openpyxl import *
wb = load_workbook('db.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('QA')

q1 = raw_input('Enter Employee Name: ')
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row):
    # changed 'row' to i
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=0).value == q1:
        # changed i to 1
        for j in range(1, sheet.max_column):
            print (sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
```